# IF UK leaves EU on March 29th, do EU holiday makers have to leave the country?

Tags: eu, brexit, citizen

hope someone can help me out. Couldn’t really find anything regarding my question.

I am a EU Citizen (Germany) and currently staying at my Girlfriends flat as a holiday in UK.

If the UK would leave right on the 29th of march, would i need to leave the UK right away or could i stay a couple of days longer past that date?

Would there be any trouble for me (somehow) at the airport when i would take a flight a few days later like start or mid of april 2019?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, even in the worst case scenario regular tourists would not be forced to leave the country. Non-EU nationals entering the UK normally get a 6 month leave to enter and there's no chance EU nationals who have already entered the UK will be treated worse than that. So if you want to be safe, make sure your trip doesn't last for more than 6 months since the date of your original entry.

> NB: **Nobody** knows for sure what's going to happen on Brexit day. Treat the above answer as speculation and check the news on March 29th to get the full answer.